# Row level access control in snowflake

Tags: security, row, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a customer that owns a carpet cleaning business and we have all of his different franchisee's data in a multi-tenant database model and we would like to move this data into a data warehouse in snowflake. I don't want to have to build a separate database for each customer because then I have to keep each database up to date with the latest data model. I want to use 1 data model to rule them all. I have a tenant ID that I keep with each record to identify the franchisee's data. I want to give a set of credentials to each franchisee to where they can hook up their analytics tool of choice (tableau, power bi, etc.) and only get access to the rows that are applicable to them. Is there a way to secure the rows they see in each table based on their user. In other words some sort of row level access control similar to profiles in postgres. Are there any better methods for handling this type of scenario? Ultimately I want to maintain and manage the least number of elt jobs and data models.

Answer (score 5):

This is the purpose of ether [Secure Views](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/views-secure.html), or [Reader Accounts](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/data-sharing-reader-create.html).

We are using both, and they have about the same technical hassle/setup costs. But we are using an internal tool to build/alter the schema's.

Comment: There is a good example here:  https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/data-sharing-secure-views.html

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Simeon's answer:

You could have a single Snowflake account and create a Snowflake role & user for each franchisee. These roles would have access to a Secure View which uses the CURRENT_ROLE / CURRENT_USER context functions as in [this example](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/views-secure.html#using-secure-views-with-snowflake-access-control) from the Snowflake documentation.

You'd have to have a role -> tennant ID "mapping table" which is used in the Secure View to limit the rows down to the correct franchisee.

Comment: So in other words I would create a mapping table of current_user to tenant id and then create secure view that joins to the mapping table and uses current_user as a filter in the view.

Comment: Yep you got it!